# Getting null value while using Dlookup

Tags: ms-access

I am not expert in access but trying to do something with Dlookup but not sure why am I getting run time error 3464

[image]

My requirement is to get details of service charges if I am entering value of engine power in text and service type in combo box. I should get service charge value in text kindly assist. Here I am attaching screenshot of table, database & dlookup

[image]

```
Dim val As Double
Dim sert As String
Dim engp As Double

sert = Me.Service_Type.Value
engp = Me.Engine_Power.Value

val = DLookup("Ser_charge", "Service_Charges", "Service_Type='sert' AND Engine_power = 'engp'")
```

from table Service_charges

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must *concatenate* the variable values, the first as text, the second as number:

```
val = DLookup("Ser_charge", "Service_Charges", "Service_Type='" & sert & "' AND Engine_power = " & engp & "")
```

And dim *val* as *Currency*. Always use Currency for amounts and the like.

Comment: Thank you lot …. yes it worked for me Thank you thank you ….

Comment: I need another help … if I just create form and add command button to save data it works perfect but when I use some editing with text then its not working .. would you help me how can I save record via coding .. table name is "Service_MasterData" I have created form with form wizard  shows error object type "service_masterdata" is not open

Comment: You should open a new question for anyone to see. But this will attempt to save the form: `If Me.Dirty = True Then Me.Dirty = False`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the values into the lookup string:

`val = DLookup("ser_charge", "service_charges", "Service_Type='" & sert & "' AND Engine_Power=" & engp)`

This is assuming that Service_type is a string, so using single quotes to wrap the variable, and engine_power is numeric, so you don't need to wrap the variable.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for your assistance and guidance …. I was just followed steps advised by gustav and issue got resolve … I am really very happy and lucky by joining here

Answer (score 0):

Have you used Nz function to return null value to 0 for example:

```
val = Nz(DLookup("Ser_charge", "Service_Charges", "Service_Type='" & sert & "' AND Engine_power = " & engp ),0)
```

That might solve your issue. Also note to remove the string quotations "" as you're dealing with a number.

Comment: You are the great … Thank bro to support … yes it helped me lot so now I am using this value every place where ever it require. Thanks lot again